# SQL Row_number() Repeat

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, impala

I am having some trouble with the following piece of code. I am working on a top basket problem where I am trying to count the number of basket combinations where each transaction should only have 4 items. The following code works well, but when a transaction buys an additional 4 items (or more) it will not be counted in the combined_basket step.

```
With RowNums as (
select 
edw_transaction_id, row_number() over (partition by edw_transaction_id     order by article_name) as row_id, article_name
from thing1
 ),


 BasketItems as (
select a.edw_transaction_id, a.article_name as _1, b.article_name as_2,c.article_name as _3,d.article_name as _4
from (select edw_transaction_id,article_name from RowNums where row_id =1) a
join (select edw_transaction_id,article_name from RowNums where row_id =2) b
on a.edw_transaction_id = b.edw_transaction_id
join (select edw_transaction_id,article_name from RowNums where row_id =3) c
on a.edw_transaction_id = c.edw_transaction_id
join (select edw_transaction_id,article_name from RowNums where row_id =4) d
on a.edw_transaction_id = d.edw_transaction_id
),

combined_basket as (
select count(*) as basket_count, _1 as basket_item1,_2 as basket_item2,_3 as basket_item3,_4 as basket_item4
from BasketItems 
group by 2,3,4,5
order by 1 desc
)

select * 
from combined_basket
order by 1 desc
limit 10
```

The Output for BasketItems looks something like this :

```
Trans Id    Row_num     Article_Name
6368773827  1   Apples
6368773827  2   Oranges
6368773827  3   Cheese
6368773827  4   Egg
6368774403  1   Apple
6368774403  2   Egg
6368774403  3   Cake
6368774403  4   Salad
6368774403  5   Egg
6368774403  6   Apple
6368774403  7   Lemon
6368774403  8   Burger
```

As you can tell from the above code it will only count the first 4 items and leave the rest (for each transaction). Is there a way to repeat the row_number function when it goes over 4 or is there another way around this problem so each transaction of 4 is counted?

The desired result would be for transaction each item is labled 1 to 4.

Comment: What would happen if you have 3 items in the order? Should you continue from 4 or should you start with 1 the next transaction?

Comment: Unless you have mysql 8+ this is not mysql code.

Comment: It would be an error if the number of items are not a multiple of 4 so it should not happen (for a given transaction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a mathematical function, i.e. Row_number % 4. This will solve the problem even without partition:

row_number() over (order by article_name) % 4 as row_id

Although, I am not 100% sure if % as a sign exists in MySQL. If it doesn't, look for modular division.

Comment: Thanks. I went with something like this in:

select 
edw_transaction_id, (row_number() over (partition by edw_transaction_id     order by article_name) % 4) +1 as row_id, article_name